# Magento 2: Is possible to apply a fixed price in cart price rule?

Tags: magento2, price-rules

I need to indicate a fixed price when the product number in the car is X.

**Example:**

When the total is equals o greather than 36 and sku is D0B33200 with price 45€

[image]

Now I need apply a fixed price in this condition (33€ per product).

Magento just lets me apply a discount and I need to apply a fixed price per product (the price would be the same for all products)

**Apply the discount on the original price**

[image]

Is it possible to indicate a fixed price in some way or by programming it?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the example what you are trying to achieve and what you are seeing right now.

Comment: Now I have added an example :)

Comment: @chdzma how did you achive this ?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting Conditions as follows

[image: conditions]

and Actions as follows

[image: actions]

This will apply 12 unit of discount for each item in the cart if the item's SKU is D0B33200 and if the item's total quantity in the cart is equal or greater than 36.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: It's a good idea but I have different discounts for clients and magento applies the discount on the discount applied to the client :(

Comment: @chdzma Sorry, didn't get your point.

Comment: We just want that if a customer buys X quantity of a product, the unique price of a product goes down to Y. But what happens is that if the customer has already a discount on that product, this new discount which we are applying would just override the old discount. I added a example.

Comment: @chdzma Set Discard subsequent rules to yes to override other discounts but it will not be applicable on the catalog price rules and if needed set the rule priority as well

Comment: I need the offer ignore the catalog rule :(((